# Android Navigation: How to fix back button behavior in Jetpack Compose NavHost?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, back-button, android-jetpack-navigation

It seems like the composable `NavHost` from `androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.5.3` does not satisfy navigation principles for back-button navigation as outlined here: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-principles

In particular: When opening the app using a deep link, the back button traverses up the app back stack, but it should leave the app instead. Am I missing anything? What can I do to correct the behavior?

Back-button behavior when opening the app with a details deep-link:

- Intended: leave app
- Actual: Navigates up the simulated app back stack

Example code to demonstrate this:
AndroidManifest.xml: Add deep link support

```
<application>
    ...
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "http://www.example.com/gizmos” -->
        <data android:scheme="http"
            android:host="www.example.com"
            android:pathPrefix="/gizmos" />
        <!-- note that the leading "/" is required for pathPrefix-->
    </intent-filter>
</application
```

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyApplicationTheme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    MainNavigation()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MainNavigation() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()

    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "start") {
        navigation(
            startDestination = "list",
            route = "start",
        ) {
            composable("list") { ListScreen(navigateToDetail = {
                navController.navigate(route = "detail/$it")
            }) }
            composable(
                route = "detail/{id}",
                arguments = listOf(
                    navArgument(name = "id") { type = NavType.LongType }
                ),
                deepLinks = listOf(
                    navDeepLink {
                        uriPattern = "http://www.example.com/gizmos/{id}"
                    }
                )
            ) { backStackEntry ->
                val id = backStackEntry.arguments?.getLong("id")

                DetailScreen(id)
            }
        }
        // TODO: Add more destinations
    }
}

@Composable
fun ListScreen(
    navigateToDetail : (Long) -> Unit,
) {
    Text("List")
    Button(onClick = {
        navigateToDetail(42)
    }) {
        Text("Navigate to 42")
    }
}

@Composable
fun DetailScreen(
    id : Long?,
) {
    Text("Detail: $id")
}
```

Comment: As per [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-deep-link#implicit), implicit deep links have two separate behaviors, depending on whether the other app launches your app with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` - a back stack **is** expected when you are on your own task. How exactly are you testing your deep link? When you go to the Recents screen, do you see your app on the other app's entry or as a completely separate entry in Recents?

Comment: I'm currently testing this via adb using the command `./adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "http://www.example.com/gizmos/1234" com.example.navanimation`, but I honestly have little understanding about the semantics of the parameters

Comment: Then yeah, since there's no other app involved, you're going to be on your own task with your own back stack, just as the documentation says. Were you unaware of the documentation I had linked or was there some other issue that you thought was occuring?

Comment: Oh, thank you! I wasn't aware that the back button event should take you to the previous app only if there is one. It's clearly mentioned in the principles of navigation that way, but I wasn't aware what "on another app's task" means. So yeah, I guess the issue was my missing knowledge about android or even mobile app development in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was not with jetpack compose navigation, but with the way I navigated to the app.

When opening the app through an intent via adb, like in `./adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "http://www.example.com/gizmos/1234" com.example.navanimation`, then the intent isn't called from another app task and therefore the back button shouldn't navigate to the app that was open previously.